# Couldn't install AudioKit 4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, audiokit

In order to install AudioKit 4.1 via CocoaPods, I did `pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.1'` on Terminal, but I got an error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- AudioKit (~> 4.1) required by Podfile

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: AudioKit (~> 4.1).
```

What's wrong?

I use Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 4):

This should be fixed now!

```
   AudioKit (4.1) successfully published
   February 13th, 17:01
   https://cocoapods.org/pods/AudioKit
   Tell your friends!
```

Comment: @sgt.kowalski That's not the most helpful of comments.

Comment: Sorry Aure, nothing was changed from the situation I posted at first.

Comment: Then your sources are not up to date, I just tested it and it works fine, finds the 4.1 version of the pod.

Comment: I did `pod repo update` and I could install AudioKit 4.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As for now, **AudioKit 4.0.4** is the latest version that you can install directly from CocoaPods. Just remove the arrow from the dependency or replace it with `~> 4.0.4`.

Alternatively, you can point the dependency to GitHub to be able to use 4.1:

```
pod 'AudioKit', :git => 'https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit.git'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but they said that they have released AudioKit 4.1.
Take a look at the site.

http://audiokit.io/downloads/

Comment: @sgt.kowalski I know that 4.1 is released. However, it's not available on CocoaPods yet.

Comment: @sgt.kowalski If you don't mind using the GitHub source as a dependency, check my updated answer.

Comment: We had some issues getting the podspec to validate, it should be resolved later today.